# how to get the colors list of a website?

Tags: color, themes

how to get the colors list of a website?
sometimes I see some beautiful website, they are colored view look,I want to anylize what colors is it used.then record color to photoshop for mysef later design. how to get these color themes?

Comment: On windows I always found Colorpic a good option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the web developer toolbar for firefox works great - [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/)

it prints hex values in organized squares and also displays rendered hex colors visually.

How to use:
Web Developer Tool Bar > Information > View Color Information

Answer (score 1):

You can also download a color picker plugin or add-on for your browser. These let you click on a colour (im canadian, we use a "u") and it tells you the hex.

Comment: I'm Swedish but have made too many errors using British English in HTML and CSS. So to me it's color: gray; not colour: grey;

Comment: http://colorzilla.com/ is a great example of this, for FF and Chrome

Comment: +1 for colorzilla.com, much faster than reading code.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few solutions that can scrape the site for colors, images, and code creating a palette for you to sample or download. Take a look at:  http://www.colorcombos.com/